# How do I bypass plaid iframe with Cypress.io?

Tags: javascript, performance, testing, automation, cypress

I'm currently doing some automation, and I'm having trouble getting over the Plaid iframe. This how it looks inside of my app:

[image]

This how is setup inside of my app:

```
<div class="PaneActions PaneActions--no-padding-top"><button
        class="TextButton TextButton--is-action TextButton--is-threads-treatment TextButton--no-margin">
        <p class="FinePrint FinePrint--is-threads-treatment">By selecting “Continue” you agree to the <u>Plaid End User
                Privacy Policy</u></p>
    </button><button
        class="Touchable-module_resetButtonOrLink__hwe7O Touchable-module_block__WBbZm Touchable-module_wide__EYer3 Button-module_button__1yqRw Button-module_large__1nbMn Button-module_centered__3BGqS"
        id="aut-continue-button" type="button" role="button"><span class="Button-module_flex__2To5J"><span
                class="Button-module_text__38wV0">Continue</span></span></button></div>
```

I'm getting the parent and the child elements, I'm looking by the text, and many other options and I'm unable to test this product. Does anyone has been working with plaid before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [Plaid demo page](https://plaid.com/demo/?countryCode=US&language=en&product=transactions) as a test app and following the steps in [Working with iframes in Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/), I managed to get a consistently working test.

From the blog, I used this sequence to ensure the iframe body has fully loaded

```
iframe -> body -> should.not.be.empty
```

The page loads a placeholder first while is waits for a GET request to complete, so just getting a loaded iframe body is not sufficient.

**placeholder**

```html
<p>iframe placeholder for https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isLinkInitialize=true&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fplaid.com&token=link-sandbox-170bce6a-fe90-44a4-8b8a-54064fbc8032&uniqueId=1&version=2.0.917</p>
```

We need to wait for the "Continue" button, which takes a bit of time to show so give it a long timeout.

Using `.contains('button', 'Continue', { timeout: 10000 })` actually returned two button, although there is only one visible.

I changed the button selector to use an id and all works consistently.

**The test**

```js
cy.visit('https://plaid.com/demo/?countryCode=US&language=en&product=transactions');

cy.contains('button', 'Launch Demo').click()

cy.get('iframe#plaid-link-iframe-1', { timeout: 30000 }).then(iframe => {

  cy.wrap(iframe)                   // from Cypress blog ref above
  .its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .should('not.be.empty')           // ensure the iframe body is loaded
  .as('iframeBody')                 // save for further commands within iframe.body

  //.contains('button', 'Continue', { timeout: 10000 })     // returns 2 buttons!

  .find('button#aut-continue-button', { timeout: 10000 })   // this is the best selector

  .click()

  cy.get('@iframeBody')
    .contains('h1', 'Select your bank')  // confirm the result of the click()


})
```

Comment: It seems that your code is working perfectly. However, I have a question, if my iframe is embedded into my webApp the body will be from my app and not for the plaid, right? 

The reason why I'm asking is that I'm getting the following error message:

```Time out error because of the contentDocument property since you will have a null value.

Comment: That is a strange message - are you using an older version of Plaid? To answer the question, you need to be careful to us the body within the iframe and not the app body, which is why I save iframe->body in an alias, then reuse it with `cy.get('@iframeBody')` rather than just `cy.get()` which would give the app body.

Comment: But your test is failing at `.its('0.contentDocument.body')` - is the iframe id different (something other than `#plaid-link-iframe-1`)? Can you inspect with devtools and find the iframe element, see what the id is. Be careful, may be there is multiple iframes in the app.

Comment: Nope, it is #plaid-link-iframe-1. It is funny because if I run this code as an individual file, I'm able to do that. For the same reason, I'm thinking that has to do something with my web app

Comment: I don't understand "run this code as an individual file"?

Comment: To debug the iframe add `.then(console.log)` after `cy.wrap(iframe)`.

Comment: Yes, I add a new spec file into my files to see if the code that you share with me is working through this link https://plaid.com/demo/?countryCode=US&language=en&product=transactions

Comment: This was the result from the console.log - wrap  <iframe#plaid-link-iframe-1>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229750/discussion-between-steve-zodiac-and-hvaandres).

Comment: this only works because you are using the same origin plaid.com to load the iframe, this will not work for anyones app beause contentDocument will be null cross origin

Answer (score 0):

- You will have to do the call for your app link
- You will have to add the following code:

```
describe('Plad Testing', () => {

    it('Request Loan', () => {


        //cy.find('Button-module_large__1nbMn', [0], { timeout: 10000 }).click()

        cy.visit('https://plaid.com/demo/?countryCode=US&language=en&product=transactions');

        cy.contains('button', 'Launch Demo').click()

        cy.get('iframe#plaid-link-iframe-1', { timeout: 30000 }).then(iframe => {

            let plaid = cy.wrap(iframe)
            plaid                   // from Cypress blog ref above
                .its('0.contentDocument.body')
                .should('not.be.empty')           // ensure the iframe body is loaded
                .as('iframeBody')                 // save for further commands within iframe.body

                //.contains('button', 'Continue', { timeout: 10000 })     // returns 2 buttons!

                .find('button#aut-continue-button', { timeout: 10000 })   // this is the best selector

                .click()

            let plaid_choose_bank = cy.get('@iframeBody')
            plaid_choose_bank
                .contains('h1', 'Select your bank')  // confirm the result of the click()
                .xpath('/html/body/reach-portal/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/button/div/div[2]/p[1]').click()
            let plaid_bank_username = cy.get('@iframeBody')
            plaid_bank_username
                .find('input[name="username"]').type('user_good', { delay: 100 })
            let plaid_bank_password = cy.get('@iframeBody')
            plaid_bank_password
                .find('input[name="password"]').type('pass_good', { delay: 100 })
            let plaid_bank_button = cy.get('@iframeBody')
            plaid_bank_button
                .find('button#aut-submit-button').click()


        })

    })

})
```

It could be possible that you get that you are not able to find the body of your iFrame. To solve this issue, we will need to add some configuration to the Cypress.json file:

```
{

"chromeWebSecurity": false,
"pageLoadTimeout": 300000,
"viewportWidth": 1536,
"viewportHeight": 960,
"includeShadowDom": true,

}
```

1. Chrome web security will prevent any CORS security from fire-up inside of the current test scenario that we have since you will have that `0.contentDocument.body` will return null if the parent origin is different from the iframe origin. This will cause the CORS security issue!
2. Page load time will help to slow loading the pages and have more time to process things
3. Viewport will help to make the browser window render like a laptop screen
4. Include shadow dom will make it easier to look for this type of element without including the "includeShadowDom" inside of your `find()` elements.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers here use `*.plaid.com` as the origin, which is why `contentDocument` is not `null`.

If you are testing this in the real world, you will be running a cross-origin `iframe` which causes `contentDocument` to be null a per the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument)

Cypress is in the process of adding official `iframe` support, but until then you can use [`cypress-iframe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) which just worked for me out of the box.

**My test**

```
 it.only('users should be able to import holdings from their broker', () => {
    cy.visit('/portfolios/created');

    cy.findByText('Import from broker').click();

    cy.frameLoaded();

    cy.iframe().findByText('Continue').click();
  });
```